# Mock interface method so that all classes that implement that interface use that implementation

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have an interface that is implemented in multiple classes. That interface has a method which returns a bool and I'm trying to mock that method so that it always returns true for unit testing purposes.

Example:

```
public interface IBase
{
}

public interface IParent
{
    bool IsValid(int number);
    ChildTypeEnum Type { get; }
}

public class A: IBase, IParent
{
    public bool IsValid(int number){...}
    ChildTypeEnum Type { get { return ...; } }
    //other methods
}

public class B: IBase, IParent
{
    public bool IsValid(int number){...}
    ChildTypeEnum Type { get { return ...; } }
    //other methods
}

public class C: IBase, IParent
{
    public bool IsValid(int number){...}
    ChildTypeEnum Type { get { return ...; } }
    //other methods
}

public class D: IBase
{
    //other methods
}
```

Is there any way to mock the IParent.IsValid() method so that I can invoke the mocked method when trying to test the ChildsEngine.ValidateParent() method?

```
public class ChildsEngine 
{
    private readonly IChildsLoader childsLoader;

    //Constructor for mocking
    public ScheduleRulesEngine(IChildsLoader childsLoader)
    {
        this.childsLoader = childsLoader;
    }


    public ParentValidation ValidateParent(int number, List<ChildTypeEnum> filterChilds = null)
    {
        var invalidChilds = new List<ChildTypeEnum>();

        var childs = childsLoader.Childs.OfType<IParent>();

        if (filterChilds != null)
            childs = childs.Where(x => filterChilds .Contains(x.Type)).ToList();

        foreach (var child in childsLoader)
        {
            if (!child.IsValid(number))
            {
                invalidChilds.Add(child.Type);
            }
        }

        return new ParentValidation (invalidChilds);
     }
   }
```

Some extra information:

- I've multiple child classes and not all of them implement the IParent interface
- The list of childs that the IChildsLoader returns includes any child that implements IBase
- On my unit testing i'm making assertions based on the ParentValidation returned by the method ChildsEngine.ValidateParent() (ex. validate if only the filter childs were considered)

The only "hack" that I've found is to set the IsValid method as virtual on the child classes, but this forces me to mock the concrete class instead of the interface, meaning that my tests are susceptible to changes if the constructor of the classes suffers changes.

Comment: can't you just mock the `ValidateParent()` method itself to return true?..

Comment: But where does the argument of type `List<IParent>` that is passed to the method come from? Do you not simply pass a `List<>` of mocks of `IParent`?

Comment: Sorry, It was missing some information that might help you to understand my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't you just stub the interface?

```
public Stub : IParent, IBase
{
    public bool IsValid(int number) { get { return true; } }
}


//Arrange
var list = Enumerable.Range(1,10).Select( 
        i => new Stub() as IBase
    ).ToList();
var o = new ClassUnderTest();

//Act
var result = o.ValidateParent(list, 7);

//Assert
Assert.IsTrue(result);
```

Comment: Added some extra info. Forgot to say that I need to have a parent list with multiple child classes (and not all of them implement the IParent interface).

Comment: Edited. Didn't change much.

Comment: I was focusing too much on mocking the interface/classes, but this stub could solve my problems. My method already works only with interfaces, so I shouldn't focus too much on the concrete classes. I was missing some abstraction on my unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

With `Moq` you can mock the interface directly.

```
var parent1 = new Mock<IParent>();
parent1.Setup(m => m.IsValid(It.IsAny<Int32>())).Returns(true);

var parent2 = new Mock<IParent>();
parent2.Setup(m => m.IsValid(It.IsAny<Int32>())).Returns(true);

List<IParent> parents = new List<IParent> { parent1.Object, parent2.Object };

Boolean testResult = ValidateParent(parents, 123);
```

**Edit**

In response to your comment below, where the list has to be a `List<IBase>`.
With `Moq` an  interface can be implemented dynamically.

```
var parent1 = new Mock<IParent>();
parent1.Setup(m => m.IsValid(It.IsAny<Int32>())).Returns(true);
IBase base1 = parent1.As<IBase>().Object; // Implement the IBase interface.

var parent2 = (new Mock<IParent>());
parent2.Setup(m => m.IsValid(It.IsAny<Int32>())).Returns(true);
IBase base2 = parent2.As<IBase>().Object;

List<IBase> bases = new List<IBase> { base1, base2 };
Boolean testResult = ValidateParent(bases, 123);
Console.WriteLine(testResult);
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that my List<IParent> is, in fact, a List<IBase> and I'm validating only the ones that implement IParent. I need to have a list that implements concrete classes, which leads to my main problem -> mocking concrete classes instead of interfaces. I was thinking about creating an interface for each of the child classes that implement IParent, but since all of them already implement IParent I was thinking that there could be a way to just mock the IParent.IsValid() method and use it everytime a class that implements that interface calls that method.